# Java. Разрешить реализацию интерфейса только наследникам некоторого класса

Tags: java, generics, полиморфизм

Попробую объяснить на примере зачем это нужно.

Под ядром системы я буду подразумевать некоторый код, правка которого мне недоступна.

Есть абстрактный класс `PersistObject`.

Ядро системы по всем его классам наследникам(в том числе и абстрактным) строит метамодель данных. Грубо говоря таблицы в базе данных. (ядро бегает по рефлексии)

Есть интерфейс `SomeInterface`.

Этим интерфейсом мы помечаем сущности, чтобы с ними можно было работать определённым образом.
И всё вроде хорошо.

Но вот у нас есть метод с сигнатурой `method(Class<SomeInterface> someInterface)`
Внутри которого используется метод ядра с сигнатурой `internal(Class<PersistObject> persistObject)`

Так вот чтобы вызвать этот метод внутри нашего, приходится писать нечто подобное:

```
Class tempClass = someInterface;
Class<PersistObject> persistObject = (Class<PersistObject>)tempClass;
internal(persistObject);
```

Это я ещё warning'и привидения типов не устранил пачкой if
'ов.

Можно было бы вместо интерфейса использовать некоторый абстрактный класс, от которого бы наследовались те классы, которые в текущей реализации реализуют `SomeInterface`.
Но, как я вначале подметил, все наследники `PersistObject`, в том числе и абстрактные, попадают в метамодель данных. А это недопустимо..

Есть ли какой-то вариант более красивый?
Было бы идеально как-то донести до интерфейса, что его могут реализовывать только наследники `PersistObject`, но не уверен, что `java` такое умеет.

**upd**:
Есть вариант (из комментариев) сменить сигнатуру на более абстрактную у метода method:

```
method(Class clazz)
```

А внутри проверять и, например, ругаться:

```
if(!clazz.isAssignableFrom(SomeInterface.class){
  throw new RuntimeException('');
}
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы этот метод могли вызывать только с таким классом в качестве параметра, который реализует интерфейс SomeInterface, и чтобы это ошибка проявлялась на стадии синтаксического анализа кода, а не Runtime...

Т.е. этот вариант **ещё хуже** текущего.

Comment: мне даже очень интересно стало,  как такое реализовать 

а если внутри method использовать instanceof и туда передать классы, которые нельзя реализовать ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, instanceof для экземпляров. В моём примере в параметрах функций передаются классы. А что значит нельзя реализовать?

Comment: тебе же нужно сделать так, чтобы внутри метода определялось класс наследуется от SomeInterface. поэтому можешь так сделать 
`internal(persistObject, Class<?>... clazzs) {
for (Class<?> clazz : clazzs)
 if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(tr.getClass())) {
  // тогда ничего не делать 
 }
}`

Comment: `if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(persistObject.getClass())`

PersistObject implements SomeInterface, верно я понял ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, нет. PersistObject - это класс ядра. SomeInterface - это мой интерфейс. Я создаю класс MyClass extends PersistObject implements SomeInterface. И вот тут проблема, описанная в вопросе.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, `persistObject.getClass()` выдаст ошибку. Т.к. это класс, а не экземпляр класса. Я, если четно, вообще не понимаю, что вы пытаетесь до меня донести. По моему я довольно четко изложил проблему.

Comment: Может не совсем верно понял проблему, но не проще ли тогда работать только с классом `PersistObject`, поскольку, исходя из вашего описания, `PersistObject` и `SomeInterface` полностью взаимозаменяемы? А `SomeInterface` можно сделать аннотацией для пометки сущностей

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, они не взаимозаменяемы. Это полностью разные по смыслу абстракции. Вы видимо вообще не поняли проблему.Я отличаю одних наследников PersistObject от других по признаку реализуют они интерфейс SomeInterface или нет. А работаю в методе method как с интерфейсом, потому что использую при работе интерфейсные методы, каким бы это вам странным не показалось:) И да, я не хочу, чтобы в метод method кто-то передал класс, который не реализует интерфейс SomeInterface, причем хочу, чтобы ругалось при компиляции, а не выполнении...

Comment: @pegoopik это другой человек написал, ну ладно ))
`MyClass extends PersistObject implements SomeInterface.
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();

SomeInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(myObject..getClass()) == true
SomeInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(MyClass.class) == true
`
означает, что MyClass реализует интерфейс SomeInterface

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, прошу прощения:) А к чему этот комментарий? как работает isAssignableFrom я конечно же в курсе.:) У меня и подобный пример в вопросе описан.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно method написать так:

```
public static  <T extends PersistObject & SomeInterface> void method(T obj) {
    PersistObject po = obj;
    SomeInterface so = obj;
    //
}
```

тогда можно будет передать только экзмепляры, которые отнаследованы от PersistObject и имплементируют SomeInterface

P.S. Проверяться всё будет на этапе компиляции, как вам и нужно

Comment: Отлично! Хотел же в вопросе спросить дополнительно, можно ли интерфейсы в генерике перечислить. Спасибо! Полностью решает проблему. На самом деле было так `<A extends SomeInterface> method(A class)`